# Setting the width of formattable() object

Tags: html, r, knitr, r-markdown

I am using the formattable package (AWESOME PACKAGE) to do some conditional formatting on a table of data that I have web scraped. I want to put the resulting object in a html document side by side with another `formattable()` table. I can't, however, figure out how to set the width of the table(either in the function or in the knitr chunk), and consequently how to put the two objects side by side.

Here is my code. I realize it is sloppy. Can someone help me put two of the same table side by side in .rmd knitting to html? It will in reality be two different formattable() tables but it doesn't really matter for this purpose.

```
library(formattable, quietly = T)
library(rvest, quietly = T)



#Part 1: Air pollution forecast from sparetheair.org
#read the page
#0-50 Good Green
#51-100 Moderate Yellow
#101-150 Unhealthy for Sensitive Groups Orange
#151-200 Unhealthy  Red
#201-300 Very Unhealthy Purple --> Also red for simplicity
air_quality <- read_html("http://sparetheair.org/stay-informed/todays-     air-quality/five-day-forecast")
#Scrape table
box <- html_nodes(air_quality,"div div .f5day")
content <- html_text(box)
#Text cleaning, removing artifacts
fulltext <- gsub("\n"," ",content)
fulltext1 <- gsub("\n"," ",fulltext)
fulltext2 <- gsub("\r"," ", fulltext1)
fulltext3 <- gsub("\t"," ", fulltext2)
#split the string into a character vector of strings
mytext <- unlist(strsplit(fulltext3," "))
#Leave empty spaces out, 
wholething <- mytext[mytext != ""]
#vector of days
Days <- wholething[1:5]
#character data for table construction
wholedata <- wholething[6:69]
#a subset of Oakland related data
baydata <- wholedata[13:26]  
#convert to data frame exactly as it is on website
mydf <- data.frame(rbind(baydata[5:9], baydata[10:14]),    row.names=c("AQI","PMI"))
#transposed data frame (tidy data, observations in rows, variables in cols)
tmydf <- data.frame(cbind(Days, baydata[5:9], baydata[10:14]), row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = F)
#replace the names of the new df with the webscraped days of the week
names(tmydf) <- c("Day","AQI","PMI")
tmydf$PMI <- gsub("PM","",tmydf$PMI)
#Print to an html table the resulting dataframe
#eventually this will have some color coding or reactive element
#focus only on numeric variables
smaller <- tmydf[1:2,]
#Coerce to numeric
smaller$AQI <- as.numeric(smaller$AQI)
smaller$PMI <- as.numeric(smaller$PMI)
#Format ouput based on scale above
nicetable <- formattable(smaller, 
                         list( 
                             AQI = formatter("span", style = x ~ 
                                                 ifelse(x <= 50, style(display = "block",`border-radius` = "4px",
                                                                       padding = "0 4px",background = "green", 
                                                                       color = "white", font.weight = "bold"), 
                                                        ifelse(x <= 100, style(display = "block",`border-radius` = "4px",
                                                                               padding = "0 4px", background = "yellow", 
                                                                               color ="white", font.weight = "bold"), 
                                                               style(display = "block",`border-radius` = "4px",
                                                                     padding = "0 4px",background = "red", 
                                                                     color = "white", font.weight = "bold") ) ) ), 
                             PMI = formatter("span",style = x ~ 
                                                 ifelse(x == 2.5, style(display = "block",`border-radius` = "4px",
                                                                        padding = "0 4px",background = "red", 
                                                                        color = "white", font.weight = "bold"), 
                                                        style(display = "block",`border-radius` = "4px",
                                                              padding = "0 4px",background = "green", 
                                                              color = "white", font.weight = "bold") ) )
                         )
)

nicetable
```

[GithubRepo](https://github.com/sco-lo-digital/CityOfOakland/blob/master/Air.R)

Comment: I'll have a look.  Sorry I forgot to respond by email.

Comment: Oh thanks Kent! No worries if you don't have time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to explain in the code, but to specify a width we just need to manually convert `formattable` to a `htmlwidget` with `as.htmlwidget()`.  This should also work in `rmarkdown`.

```
library(formattable, quietly = T)
library(rvest, quietly = T)



#Part 1: Air pollution forecast from sparetheair.org
#read the page
#0-50 Good Green
#51-100 Moderate Yellow
#101-150 Unhealthy for Sensitive Groups Orange
#151-200 Unhealthy  Red
#201-300 Very Unhealthy Purple --> Also red for simplicity
air_quality <- read_html("http://sparetheair.org/stay-informed/todays-air-quality/five-day-forecast")
#Scrape table
box <- html_nodes(air_quality,xpath="//div//div[contains(@class, 'f5day')]")
content <- html_text(box)
#Text cleaning, removing artifacts
fulltext <- gsub("\n"," ",content)
fulltext1 <- gsub("\n"," ",fulltext)
fulltext2 <- gsub("\r"," ", fulltext1)
fulltext3 <- gsub("\t"," ", fulltext2)
#split the string into a character vector of strings
mytext <- unlist(strsplit(fulltext3," "))
#Leave empty spaces out, 
wholething <- mytext[mytext != ""]
#vector of days
Days <- wholething[1:5]
#character data for table construction
wholedata <- wholething[6:69]
#a subset of Oakland related data
baydata <- wholedata[13:26]  
#convert to data frame exactly as it is on website
mydf <- data.frame(rbind(baydata[5:9], baydata[10:14]),    row.names=c("AQI","PMI"))
#transposed data frame (tidy data, observations in rows, variables in cols)
tmydf <- data.frame(cbind(Days, baydata[5:9], baydata[10:14]), row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = F)
#replace the names of the new df with the webscraped days of the week
names(tmydf) <- c("Day","AQI","PMI")
tmydf$PMI <- gsub("PM","",tmydf$PMI)
#Print to an html table the resulting dataframe
#eventually this will have some color coding or reactive element
#focus only on numeric variables
smaller <- tmydf[1:2,]
#Coerce to numeric
smaller$AQI <- as.numeric(smaller$AQI)
smaller$PMI <- as.numeric(smaller$PMI)
#Format ouput based on scale above
nicetable <- formattable(smaller, 
                         list( 
                           AQI = formatter("span", style = x ~ 
                                             ifelse(x <= 50, style(display = "block",`border-radius` = "4px",
                                                                   padding = "0 4px",background = "green", 
                                                                   color = "white", font.weight = "bold"), 
                                                    ifelse(x <= 100, style(display = "block",`border-radius` = "4px",
                                                                           padding = "0 4px", background = "yellow", 
                                                                           color ="white", font.weight = "bold"), 
                                                           style(display = "block",`border-radius` = "4px",
                                                                 padding = "0 4px",background = "red", 
                                                                 color = "white", font.weight = "bold") ) ) ), 
                           PMI = formatter("span",style = x ~ 
                                             ifelse(x == 2.5, style(display = "block",`border-radius` = "4px",
                                                                    padding = "0 4px",background = "red", 
                                                                    color = "white", font.weight = "bold"), 
                                                    style(display = "block",`border-radius` = "4px",
                                                          padding = "0 4px",background = "green", 
                                                          color = "white", font.weight = "bold") ) )
                         )
)

nicetable

#  so what happens is a formattable object
#   gets converted to an htmlwidget
#   for viewing when interactive
#  to specify a width
#   we have to do the htmlwidget conversion ourselves
#   with as.htmlwidget
as.htmlwidget(nicetable, width=200)



# just use shiny to get helper fluid functions
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)

browsable(
  tagList(
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 6,
        as.htmlwidget(nicetable)
      ),
      column(
        width = 6,
        as.htmlwidget(nicetable)
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Hi Kent, I actually get this error when I try to use as.htmlwidget in rmd   pandoc: Could not determine mime type for `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/shiny/www/shared/bootstrap/css/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2'
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
Execution halted`

Comment: would have thought RStudio would have removed the woff2, but I guess they have not.  I also remembered that formattable includes bootstrap, so I changed the answer to use the formattable bootstrap dependency.

Comment: Hi Kent, Thanks for the help. So is there a way I can remove the woff2/ change font in `style()`? I see your update on the formattable bootstrap dependence. Ty!

Comment: would require a pull or issue to Shiny

Comment: Thx to @timelyportfolio for the lead on rstudio flexdashboard template! This addressed my issue trying to format the width on my formattable tables. https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard

Comment: Is there a way to control the height as well? When using as.htmlwidget, the height parameter doesn't seem to do anything, and the table always defaults to the height of the text.

Comment: this is caused by bootstrap css.  You can do with `htmltools`.  Hard to put code in comment, but something like this.  `browsable(tags$div(style = "overflow-y: scroll; height:200px;", as.htmlwidget(ft)))`. Eliminate the `browsable` if you are using in rmarkdown.